# Can I schedule events/callbacks at specified times each day in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

Is there any way (in PhoneGap) I can schedule events or callbacks to happen at designated times each day?

I guess I'm looking for something like Android AlarmManager, so that I can trigger some notification each day at a certain time, that would then prompt the user to launch my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this:

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git

It allows you to use local notifications of the device.

Once you have installed this plugin you gain access to the `window.plugin.notification.local` variable. You can then run:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
    date: new Date(),
    message: 'Your notification message'
});
```

This will set a notification to appear on the users device at the specified date.

I have used this with [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com) to handle my timed notifications.

Comment: This only sets a notification to appear at user's device, how to some specific task like call a function to call webservice api ?