# PhoneGap (Cordova) start tracking GPS on a specific time

Tags: android, ios, cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a Phonegap application which requires GPS tracking. The tracking is required only at a certain time. For example, the event start at 5 o clock, then I want to start tracking at 5 o clock only. Any option for doing it background. The app is developing for iOS and Android.
Is there any option for doing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you -> [Can i schedule events in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115844/can-i-schedule-events-callbacks-at-specified-times-each-day-in-phonegap) but i think, this will only work on Android. I don't know how you could realise this on iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this link is helpful for registering notifications, but not GPS. I am looking for the same way of handling GPS.

Comment: You could change the code or you can do a notification everyday at the same time to open the application. I don't think it's possible to track the users position in Background to a scheduled time :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlermManager class in that create broadcast when broadcast wakeup then u can call 
gps enable and track location according to that same for stop gps location also

Comment: Will try the same and share the update... Thanks for the idea